# How to use Redis for http requests cache in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, redis, http-caching

I want to cache results of some HTTP requests to my Symfony 3.4 application using Symfony HttpCache.
Following their [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/http_cache.html#http-cache-introduction) I now have those lines in app_dev.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

This is my controller code

```
    $overview = $this->channelRepository->getOverview();
    $response = new JsonResponse($overview);
    $response->setSharedMaxAge(3600);
    return $response;
```

And this is my config.yml

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: snc_redis.default
    #...
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: phpredis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
            logging: false
```

However, I don't see new entries appear in my redis server. Instead, those entries appear in filesystem cache (var/cache/dev/http/cache). How do I fix my application to use Redis HTTP cache?

I dug a bit deeper and found out that `AppCache` that I use extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache` which only accepts filesystem store. Does that mean that I should somehow use `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache`, which accepts any Store in its constructor?

Comment: Are you entirely sure you want to use `Redis` to cache your API responses? For such purpose `Varnish` is the common tool.

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski hmmmmm. In this case lack of documentation on what I was asking makes sense...

Comment: Here is working prototype with HTTP Redis cache https://github.com/codereviewvideos/docker-symfony3-redis-example/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L35

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski Yeah, I saw that. But that example is a bit different from what I wanted to do. Anyway, best answer for my question is "don't do it".

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski does example you describe let the Http Cache use Redis? To me it seems the storage mechanism of HttpCache is hardcoded to the cache dir: https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/4.4/HttpCache/HttpCache.php#L82